# How to call useContractReads with typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I try to use wagmi with typescript but I'm quite new to typescript. Passing an address as arg throw an error, what is the way to solve this ?

I've read https://wagmi.sh/docs/typescript and I also tried to create a custom interface (and defining arg?: ...)
for configCryptoDevsToken but then the call to useContractReads failed when I provided the contracts object, and I'm not even sure it's the right way to do this.

There is a mwe  : [here](https://github.com/Fabien-Morrow/mwe)

```js
import { abi } from "../constants/CryptoDevsToken";
import { useContractReads } from "wagmi";

export function useCryptoDevsToken(address: string | undefined) {
  const configCryptoDevsToken = {
    address: "CRYPTODEVSTOKEN_GOERLI_ADDRESS",
    abi: abi,
  };
  let contracts = [
    {
      ...configCryptoDevsToken,
      functionName: "maxSupply",
    },
  ];
  if (address) {
    contracts.push({
      ...configCryptoDevsToken,
      functionName: "balanceOf",
      args: [address], // throwing an error, see below
    });
  }
  const { data } = useContractReads({
    contracts: contracts,
  });
  return { data };
}
```

The error throwed

```
Argument of type '{ functionName: string; args: string[]; address: string; abi: ({ inputs: { internalType: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; stateMutability: string; type: string; anonymous?: undefined; name?: undefined; outputs?: undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; })[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ functionName: string; address: string; abi: ({ inputs: { internalType: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; stateMutability: string; type: string; anonymous?: undefined; name?: undefined; outputs?: undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; })[]; }'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'args' does not exist in type '{ functionName: string; address: string; abi: ({ inputs: { internalType: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; stateMutability: string; type: string; anonymous?: undefined; name?: undefined; outputs?: undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; })[]; }'.
```

Comment: Did you figure that out, Fabien? Thanks. I'm trying to figure out proper type casting for wagmi return type, too...

Answer (score 0):

Your error looks like a type error in your abi.

For wagmi to use type inference on abis you need to use a const assertion.
It is explained further here.
https://wagmi.sh/core/typescript

This is how I would do it.

```js
import { useContractReads } from "wagmi";
import ABI from "../abis/abi.json";
const { abi: MY_ABI } = ABI;

export function useCryptoDevsToken(address: string | undefined) {
  const configCryptoDevsToken = {
    address: "CRYPTODEVSTOKEN_GOERLI_ADDRESS",
    abi: MULTICALL_ABI,
  };
  let contracts = [
    {
      ...configCryptoDevsToken,
      functionName: "maxSupply",
    },
  ];
  if (address) {
    contracts.push({
      ...configCryptoDevsToken,
      functionName: "balanceOf",
      args: [address], // throwing an error, see below
    });
  }
  const { data } = useContractReads({
    contracts: contracts,
  });
  return { data };
}
```